# How to filter out conditional logic elements in a nested list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, boolean-logic

I have a list of pre-requisites for a given task. The list consists of other tasks (using letters as place holders) which make up a logical expression. Example shown below:

```
prereqList = [["A", "|", "B"], "&", [["C", "&", "D"], "|", "E"], "&", "F"]
```

I also have a list of completed tasks:

```
completedTasks = ["A", "C", "F"]
```

I am trying to remove the completed tasks from the prereqList while following the conditional logic. For the aforementioned example, I would expect the output to be:

```
filtered_list = ["D", "|", "E"]
```

What I have so far:

```
def filter_prereqs(prereqList, completedTasks):
    ops = {
            "&": (lambda a, b: a in completedTasks and b in completedTasks),
            "|": (lambda a, b: a in completedTasks or b in completedTasks)
        }
        for i in range(prereqList):
            if isinstance(prereqList[i], list):
                filter_prereqs(prereqList[i], completedTasks)
            else:
                if prereqList[i] not in ops.keys():
                    pass
                else:
                    conditionMet = ops[prereqList[i]](prereqList[i-1],prereqList[i+1])
                    if conditionMet:
```

Been stuck trying to figure this out for a while. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the expected outcome when `prereqList` is `["A", "&", "B"]`, and `completedTasks` is `["A", "B"]`?

Comment: `for i in range(prereqList):` doesn't make sense

Comment: How important is it to support expressions like `["A", "&", "B", "&", "C"]`? I have an idea but it only works if each sublist is exactly three elements long, for example `[["A", "&", "B"], "&", "C"]`.

Comment: @Kevin in response to your first comment, the expected outcome would be an empty list. For your second comment, most of the sublists are 3 elements long but not all of them.

Comment: @pault I am using i in range prereqList to iterate through the list and so I can access the element before and after i (i-1 and i+1). If there is a better method, I am open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial solution:

This works, but only on expressions that are "conservatively bracketed". In other words, it can parse `[["A", "&", "B"], "&", "C"]`, but not `["A", "&", "B", "&", "C"]`. So I can't parse the exact expression in your question, but I can parse a logically equivalent version of it that has an extra pair of brackets.

```
#sentinel value that gets returned for an expression that's 100% completed
complete = object()

def remove_completed(expression, completed):
    if isinstance(expression, str):
        if expression in completed:
            return complete
        else:
            return expression
    left, operator, right = expression
    left = remove_completed(left, completed)
    right = remove_completed(right, completed)
    if operator == "|":
        if left is complete or right is complete:
            return complete
        else:
            return [left, "|", right]
    elif operator == "&":
        if left is complete:
            return right
        elif right is complete:
            return left
        else:
            return [left, "&", right]

prereqList = [[["A", "|", "B"], "&", [["C", "&", "D"], "|", "E"]], "&", "F"]
result = remove_completed(prereqList, ["A", "C", "F"])
print(result)
```

Result:

```
['D', '|', 'E']
```

Comment: This is great. I should be able to implement conservative bracketing in the lists. Thanks for your help!